# Stored procedure to perform different tasks?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer table.

I have created stored procedure I can use to insert new data into the table. But what if I wanted to use the same procedure to update OR delete data from that table. Could I do this easily or do I have to use a separate function/procedure for each function?

```
create or replace procedure add_customer(custid in table.id%type,
name table.name%type) 
is
begin
insert into table(id, name)
values(id, name);
commit;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameter like `action` in example below and use it in code:

```
create or replace procedure modify_customer(
  action in varchar2, custid in table.id%type, custname table.name%type) 
is
begin
if action = 'insert' then
  insert into table(id, name) values(custid, name);
  commit;
elsif action = 'delete' then 
  delete from table where id = custid and name = custname;
  commit;
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a discriminator parameter to your add_customer procedure which says whether the action is INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. Based on this parameter you can create the required insert, update or delete statement. This way you will be able to use a common procedure for all the actions.

As far as using one procedure or multiple procedures, if the table is a simple one with limited number of columns, one procedure should do fine. But once the number of columns increases in the table, one procedure might become more complicated than required.